# Bilingual application name on blackberry with webworks

Tags: html, localization, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm packaging an HTML5/Javascript application with WebWorks for BlackBerry.
In the config.xml file, we can set the icon and the name to be display on the phone.
The elements to use for that purpose are:

```
<name>App Name</name> 
<icon src="images/icon.png"/>
```

My problem is that my app is bilingual and I have a different name in english and in French
(ex: "Billing" in english and "Facturation" in french).

I want "Billing" to appear below the icon when the phone language is set to english and "Facturation" when the phone language is set to french.

Is there a way to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name can also be localized:

```
    <name>Localization Example</name>
    <name xml:lang="ca">Exemple de localisation</name>
    <name xml:lang="fr_FR">Exemple de localisation</name>
    <name xml:lang="de_DE">Localization Probe</name>
```

Source: https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Localization